# How to remember a non-consumable Unity IAP the right way

Tags: unity, in-app-purchase

I have implemented Unity 5's IAP system through Google Play. I read a few guides that mention not to store completed purchases in `PlayerPrefs` because it is clear text and easy to hack, but none mention the correct way to "remember" purchases. For example, when re-installing an Anroid app, purchases are restored the first time the app runs by individual calls to this method defined in the Unity IAP API.

```
public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase (PurchaseEventArgs e)
    {
        //my Playerpref save that I want to avoid is here.
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }
```

On subsuqent app runs, this method is not called again. Is there a way to query past purchases other than saving them in `PlayerPrefs`?

Answer (score 3):

on Android the storeController has a list of purchased products when initialized successfully. So then you can use code that looks something like this and check if the item is bought :

```
Product product = storeController.products.WithID(productId);
 if (product != null && product.hasReceipt)
 {
     // Owned Non Consumables and Subscriptions should always have receipts.
     // So here the Non Consumable product has already been bought.
     itemBought = true;
 }
```

Restoring purchases is not needed on the Android platform. It is only needed on iOS.

Comment: also I wanted to note for others, while restoring through a special function is not needed on Android, one would need to set up the function I mention and use the code you posted to get everything working correctly.

Comment: I made a follow up question concerning not being able to use the above method for times without internet: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140345/unity-iap-through-google-play-is-forgotten-after-a-day-without-internet-connecti