# Unity IAP through Google Play is forgotten after a day without internet connection

Tags: unity, networking, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am trying to make a NonConsumable IAP purchase persist without internet connection.

I have implemented the IAP system from Unity 5.6 through Google Play for a NonConsumable item and it is working. From a previous [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140046/how-to-remember-a-non-consumable-unity-iap-the-right-way) I learned how to avoid using Unity's `PlayerPrefs` to remember purchases in favor of checking the receipt from the Unity storeController that initializes with Unity's API code below.

```
   public void OnInitialized (IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
            this.extensions = extensions;
        }
```

What I have observed is that the `OnInitialized` will run without internet connection as long as it has recently been initialized. This seems to be cached somewhere within Android because clearing the cache on my app will not force the purchase to be forgotten. **The problem is after about half a day without internet connection the controller cannot initialize. Therefore I cannot check the item receipt in the controller with the code below.**

```
Product product = storeController.products.WithID(productId);
 if (product != null && product.hasReceipt)
 {
     // Owned Non Consumables and Subscriptions should always have receipts.
     // So here the Non Consumable product has already been bought.
     itemBought = true;
 }
```

What strategy or method should I use to persist a NonConsumable purchase during times without internet connection as it is recommended to not use `Playerprefs` on numerous guides.

Comment: You're running on an Android device? You should have access to write files to a (private) directory on the device. You can "safely" save any data you want there. It's more secure than PlayerPrefs because you can encode the data in binary, encrypt it, or just obfuscate the hell out of it, unlike with PlayerPrefs which stores values in plain text. Ostensibly it's still not 100% secure, but as long as you're attempting to validate with the server *first* you should be fine.

Comment: As a note on the research I did, I found one forum that said that the behavior I noted above is a bug in Unity's IAP system, but no Unity moderator confirmed that.

Comment: Possible. I haven't messed with it yet myself.

Comment: How is this approach supposed to work in terms of who owns the purchase? In other words, a purchase is associated with an account, so if you store a file locally to indicate the purchase has been made, then multiple accounts can make use of the purchase even though they didn't actually buy the product..

Comment: Another concern is refunds. If an account refunds a product, will the hasReceipt become false automatically (as long as the device is not offline) when the refund takes place?

Comment: What I did with this approach is to check the receipt on app launch every time the app launches and is connected online. If ever the receipt says the user no longer owns the product, the player pref is cleared. I'm not saying this is the best way to do it, but it's worked okay so far.

Comment: And I'm not sure if unity's IAP system detects refunds or not but it has been getting updates regularly, so hopefully it does. Look up how to include your Google Play Dev account's public key into the Unity IAP. If you do so it helps with detecting fraudulent purchases and use of the IAP.